# Generated JAR throws ClassNotFoundException for main class

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jar

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA to create a JAR. I selected "JAR from modules with dependencies" and "extract to the target JAR" for library JARs - the generated JAR looks just fine:

```
myJar.jar
  |
  +- META-INF
  |  +- MANIFEST.MF
  +- com
  |  +- my
  |     +- package
  |        +- Main.class
  +- some dependencies...
```

I checked twice: all the needed dependencies are present. The `Main-Class` field in `MANIFEST.MF` points to the correct main class (`com.my.package.Main` in this example). I've opened the file in my archive tool and inspected it using

```
jar tf myJar.jar
```

and both show that the classes needed are available (also `Main.class`). I've left the `Classpath` field in IntelliJ's wizard empty, as I do not need any external libraries. However, when I issue

```
java -jar myJar.jar
```

it throws the following exception:

```
Error: could not find or load main class com.my.package.Main
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.my.package.Main
```

I've followed [this guide by JetBrains](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2010/08/quickly-create-jar-artifact/)
, and IntelliJ automatically added all dependencies from the Maven `pom.xml` to be extracted into the JAR, which is correct.

Am I missing something I should configure here and how comes that this does not work?

(Note: Generating a JAR from that project also does not work when I choose "copy to output folder and link via manifest" for the library JARs.)

(Note 2: Using `maven-assembly-plugin` is sadly not an option since I referenced other IntelliJ workspace modules which would then not get included.)

---

**Update:** That it should work as-is shows also the following phenominum: When I unzip my JAR and do

```
java -cp . com.my.package.Main
```

in the created directory, it works without any problems, which is strange given that Java refuses to load it...

Comment: Take a look into the jar of it realy contains the class

Comment: @Jens I did. Both my archive tool and `jar tf myJar.jar` show that the class is available (as I wrote in the question).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my case, my JAR did not work as expected due to some signed JAR dependencies.

These JARs bring a signature and key file, which also gets extracted when you embed the signed JARs. There is basically no risk in removing them, but they are one of the many possible reasons your JAR may not work.

**How to remove such signatures from a JAR?**
I'm describing the following steps for Linux/Darwin, but I think that there is a similar way for Windows.

1. *Unpack you JAR.*
   Since JARs are nothing more than simple ZIP archives, you can use `unzip`:

   ```sh
   mkdir temporaryDirectory
   unzip myJar.jar -d temporaryDirectory/
   ```

   The `-d` option is optional, but it helps keeping your directory structure clean because it sets the target directory.
2. *Locate the signature files.*
   The signature files (or keys) are located in the `META-INF/` directory, so change there:

   ```sh
   cd temporaryDirectory/META-INF/
   ```

   Next, we need to find the troubling files. They have the file extensions `.SF` (for the signature) and `.DSA` for the key file:

   ```sh
   ll | grep '.DSA\|.SF'
   ```
3. *Delete (or rename) the signature and key files.*
   Renaming these files bares the benefit that you can restore them later (for whatever reason), deleting them also does the trick but is a bit more risky:

   - Deleting:

     ```sh
     rm signature.DSA signature.SF
     # Either enter the name of the files
     # instead of 'signature' or use * to delete any:
     # rm *.DSA *.SF
     ```
   - Renaming:

     ```sh
     rename 's/\.DSA$/.DSA.old/' *  # Append ".old" to all .DSA files
     rename 's/\.SF$/.SF.old/' *    # Append ".old" to all .SF files
     ```
4. *Repacking your JAR.*
   Still in `temporaryDirectory/`, we can repack our JARs to make them work:

   ```sh
   cd ../                      # If you're still in temporaryDirectory/META-INF
   jar cfm ../myWorkingJar.jar ./META-INF/MANIFEST.MF -C ./ .
   ```

   Explanation:

   - `jar cfm`
     `jar` is Java's built-in JAR builder. Invoking it with `c` means that we want to create a JAR, `f` stands for the output file (which we specify next) and `m` is for the `MANIFEST.MF` we want to use. If you omit `m`, `jar` will write an empty `MANIFEST.MF` to the JAR.
   - `../myWorkingJar.jar`
     This is the path we want to output our JAR to. It belongs to `f` which we specified earlier.
   - `./META-INF/MANIFEST.MF`
     This is the manifest file we want to use. It belongs to the `m` of `cfm`.
   - `-C ./`
     This means that our `.class` files are located in this directory (`.`).
   - `.` (last argument)
     This specifies that we want to add this directory to the JAR.

   If you want a detailed description of what `jar` is doing, you can issue the command from above with `cvfm` instead of `cfm` (`v` stands for verbose).
5. *Verify that it works.*
   All set, now you can check that your JAR is working as intended by issuing

   ```sh
   java -jar myWorkingJar.jar
   ```
6. *Removing the temporary directory.*
   Since you're finished repairing your JAR, you can safely delete the temporary directory we created (and/or the "broken" JAR).

I've created a simple BASH script which "automates" this process a **little** bit:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
JARNAME=myJar.jar          # enter your JAR's name here
OUT_JARNAME=myJar_out.jar  # enter your output JAR's name here

# Creating the directory, unpacking the JAR, entering META-INF/
mkdir temp
unzip $JARNAME -d temp
cd temp/META-INF

# Renaming the troublemakers.
rename 's/\.DSA$/.DSA.old/' *
rename 's/\.SF$/.SF.old/' *

# Reassembling the JAR
cd ../
jar cfm ../$OUT_JARNAME ./META-INF/MANIFEST.MF -C ./ .
cd ../

# Uncomment this line if you wish to delete the temp directory upon finish.
# rm -r temp
```

I hope this helps people also encountering this issue.

Comment: Hi, I don't have any signature files but still my jar doesn't work
Is there anything else to check?

Comment: It's best you ask a completely new question with as much detail as possible, for example including the output of `jar tf <your_file>` so as to check if the "missing" class is actually inside the built JAR.