# Java JAR: Could not find or load main class

Tags: java, jar, program-entry-point

I know this question has been asked a lot, but I have tried a few suggestions and am still getting this error.

I am running the jar as follows:

`java -jar MyJar-1.0.jar com.me.ldap.ActiveMain`,

where my ActiveMain.java file looks like this:

package com.me.ldap;

```
public class ActiveMain {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ...
    }
}
```

I have also tried simply `java -jar MyJar-1.0.jar` with the same `Error: Could not find or load main class` error. I've also looked into the class path option but I don't think that applies.

I am creating it in Intellij as a Maven project. `Maven` > `Lifecycle` > `package`.

Comment: how are you creating jar file?

Comment: I am creating it in Intellij as a Maven project. Maven > Lifecycle > package

Answer (score 5):

In order for:

```
java -jar myfile.jar
```

to work, there must be a manifest file in the jar file that points to a main class.

In order for you to specify the main class on the command line, you need to specify a classpath, not a jar file. Like:

```
java -cp myfile.jar com.me.ldap.ActiveMain
```

You are conflating these two things. Either create a manifest that specifies your main class and use the -jar switch, or simply use the -cp switch and specify your main class on the command line.

Comment: Thank you. I had the manifest file but did not specify the main class.

Comment: @formicaman Would u mind specifying how to specify the main class? I have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried removing the signature files? I have seen this error pop up sometimes when due to signature files as documented in ["Invalid signature file" when attempting to run a .jar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/999489/invalid-signature-file-when-attempting-to-run-a-jar) and [Generated JAR throws ClassNotFoundException for main class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50934390/generated-jar-throws-classnotfoundexception-for-main-class) is also in the similar vein.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](/help/whats-reputation). If not, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.

Comment: I amended the answer to say try removing the signature files as a solution.